# setter injection guice + wicket

Tags: wicket, guice

I have a Wicket Web Page where I create a new Object of class A:
A a = new A(User u);

In A I would like to have setter injection, however this is actually not done. I have heard that one must provide an empty constructor but how is it possible to have also a non - empty constructor with setter injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Wicket, but I assume that you've got various things on your Wicket web page annotated with `@Inject`, yes?

So, you have a few options; in order of preference:

- If you're `@Inject`ing your `User`, one option is to annotate the constructor of `A` with `@Inject` and then in your page, just `@Inject` either an `A` or a `Provider<A>` into web page.
- You can `@Inject` into your web page a `MembersInjector<A>` (call it `aMembersInjector`) and then after you create your `A` object call `aMembersInjector.injectMembers(a)` to cause all the setter injection to happen.
- You can `@Inject` into your web page the `Injector` and call `Injector.injectMembers(a)` after you create your `A`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. Regardless, try taking a look at

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561578/wicket-dependency-injection)
- [Wicket Spring integration](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/spring.html)
- [Wicket Guice integration](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/guice-integration-pitfall.html)

at see if any examples there shed light on your problem.